# Can an iPad be used as a development machine to create iPad applications?

Tags: ipad

My wife has a iPad and I was wondering if I could use it to develop iPad applications? I am assuming the answer is no.

Comment: Did you look at the apple developer site for the iPad? http://developer.apple.com/ipad/sdk/

Comment: Do you mean develop apps on the iPad itself (e.g. write code on the iPad)?

Comment: Yes, writing code on the iPad is what I am looking for.

Comment: Oded. No I have not. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 9):

Apple's development guidelines ban apps of this type from the store, so no you unfortunately cannot use the iPad to make iPad software (You can test the programs you write on your Mac on the iPad though).  You need a Mac and the XCode IDE to actually create iPad / iPhone applications.  You can learn more about this at http://developer.apple.com/

EDIT:

While it isn't possible to directly write code that runs on the iPad, you certainly can write code on the device itself.  There is an app available in the app store called [CodeToGo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codetogo/id382677229?mt=8) that lets you author programs in quite a few different languages.  When you want to run your program, the code is actually uploaded to a server, executed there, and the results of that run are returned to you.  This, or a similar program, is the closest you will currently get to writing code on the iPad (or iPhone).

Here is [an article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/08/23/ipad_apps/page2.html) that talks about / reviews code editing programs for iOS.

Comment: As I understand dakira's question, he is asking if he can make an app for iPad on an iPad itself.  Apple does not allow apps that run / execute code (virtual machines) into the app store (unless they use an officially provided API).  This means no emulators, IDE's, etc are allowed into the app store.

Comment: Well, if that is the case, then question needs to be revised.

Comment: dakira did clarify the meaning of his question in the comments, he is indeed looking to write code on the iPad.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have developed some applications for the Android and would like to port them to applications that can run on the iPad/iTouch platforms. But I do not have a Mac to do so. My wife has recently purchased a iPad and was wondering of I could use it to port/developed application using the iPad itself. Instead of purchasing a Mac to do it. I think the conversation has given me enough information to go a do some research. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Codify](http://twolivesleft.com/Codify/). Not the whole 'write anything, run anywhere' experience, but a step in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. If you are a Lua developer, I recommend [Codea](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/) (formerly known as Codify). For Python developers, I recommend [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/). Both apps allow you to write and test code in-app, and they even include support for graphics such as games. There is a GitHub project that actually lets you compile Codea projects into full-blown AppStore apps, the [Codea Runtime](https://github.com/TwoLivesLeft/Codea-Runtime). The app [Touchline](http://touchlinegame.com/PressRelease.html) is one such application.

Unfortunately, there is not currently an official way to compile Pythonista apps and sell them on the AppStore. The developer has, however, made a utility that allows you to install webclip based icons on the homescreen that will run a Pythonista script. Also, there are  plans to incorporate an export to Xcode mechanism in a future update of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://www.slideshare.net/carlbrown/developing-ios-apps-on-your-ipad-with-xcab

I haven't tried it myself, but apparently he's created a way to code on the iPad, upload the code, download the compiled project, install it, and run it, all from the iPad.  He says you cant do gui stuff, but at least you can do the logic on the run.

Answer (score 0):

If you make for instance ruby on rails applications and let them have a mobile theme they can run in the safari browser of the ipad. The benefit of this is that you don't need Apple to review your code. The cons are that you can't use the appstore to sell and distribute your app.

But it can look and feel like a native ipad app.
I'm exploring this business model right now and would like to hear if others have done this.

Your app will run on an external server like Heroku, be archived on github.

Answer (score -1):

Try CppCode - C/C++ IDE & Compiler that works on iPad/iPhone. http://cppcode.info